AND IF using variable in WHERE CLAUSE
Im am creating a stored procedure in MySQL. When calling the procedure you pass along your OfficeId as well as a ClientId (Insurer). The below code is only returning results when the insurerId is 0. It is not returning any results with any other InsurerId. Any pointers will be appriciated
FROM
    Office O
    INNER JOIN Claim C
        ON C.OfficeId = O.Id
    INNER JOIN ClaimItems CI
        ON CI.ClaimId = C.Id
    INNER JOIN Client I
        ON I.Id = C.InsurerId
WHERE
    O.Id = @officeid
    AND IF(@insurerid = 0, '1=1', CONCAT('I.Id = ', @insurerid))


Please do not post screenshots of code, post the actual code as code-formatted text, and the exact error you get.

So in my application I have a combobox where the user can choose which client(insurer). Index 0 is "All". If 0 is sent to the SP then I do not want any filtering on the I.Id. That is the idea anyways. I hope this makes sense.

The evaluated experession 'I.Id = 123' is a string and does not convert to TRUE.
Looks like you should to do something like:
FROM
    Office O
    INNER JOIN Claim C
        ON C.OfficeId = O.Id
    INNER JOIN ClaimItems CI
        ON CI.ClaimId = C.Id
    INNER JOIN Client I
        ON I.Id = C.InsurerId
WHERE
    O.Id = @officeid
    AND (@insurerid = 0 or I.Id = @insurerid)

Btw, MySQL stored procedures do not use @var syntax in parameters. These are user defined variables.

This worked perfectly! Thank you. Regarding @var, I am first testing with user defined variables before moving the script over to the SP.
